# Erro ao instalar o magento "PHP Extension mcrypt must be loaded..."

Tags: php, magento, xampp

Estou fazendo a instalação do [magento](/questions/tagged/magento) em localhost, mas ao iniciar a instalação do tal , me retorna um erro

> PHP Extension mcrypt must be loaded...

Sou leigo no assunto , alguém sabe como resolve ?

Comment: Você está tentando instalar em ubuntu ?

Comment: Você precisa intalar o mcypt no servidor local http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mcrypt.setup.php

Comment: @ErlonCharles creio que o problema é a versão do PHP, no PHP7.2 isto foi removido de vez, já que era um módulo obsoleto a algum tempo.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimentoP. ele não mencionou a versão do php que ele está usando, não há como adivinhar de ele está usando uma versão recente ou antiga. Mas pela mensagem de erro o problema é a falta deste módulo.

Comment: @ErlonCharles é que se tratando exclusivamente do XAMPP, eles não usam versões antigas do PHP a anos, presumi então que o problema fosse por ser php7 ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O módulo *mcrypt* já era obsoleto desde o PHP 5.5 (ao menos várias funções dele) e foi removido de vez no PHP7.2, conforme o link http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php:

> **Warning** This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.
>
> Alternatives to this feature include:
>
> - [Sodium](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sodium.php) (available as of PHP 7.2.0)
> - [OpenSSL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php)

Essa mensagem esta aparecendo pra você pois provavelmente a versão que esta usando do **Magento** é bem antiga ou então você esta usando o PHP7 na sua máquina local.

Não tem como habilitar este módulo no PHP7, pois simplesmente não existe mais para PHP7 e no PHP5 se for Windows só baixando a `.dll` de alguma fonte externa, **no entanto o que recomendo é que atualize o Magento!**

Se for Ubuntu e PHP 5 você pode tentar instalar via repositório (talvez esteja disponivel) através do comando:

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

Depois:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/conf.d/mcrypt.ini /etc/php5/mods-available/mcrypt.ini
```

Em seguida habilite a extensão usando php5enmod e reinicie o Apache:

```
sudo php5enmod mcrypt
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Se algo falhar, principalmente no `apt-get` é porque provavelmente a Ubuntu já removeu este módulo dos repositórios.

Comment: Acho que vou instalar uma versão mais recente então ..

Comment: i am configuring an existing magento project on WAMP server with PHP 7.2, and i am getting the same error, can you please suggest how to resolve it

Comment: Hi @Vikky .. Upgrade Magento for lastet version or downgrade PHP for version 5.